# Sending e-mail from a LightSwitch application

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-lightswitch

Updated for bounty. What I am after is a simple way to send e-mail when I click a button on one of my LightSwitch Screens. I need to be able to access data from any screen (to collect and process it) so it can be sent as an e-mail. How can this be done without breaking my back over it, or using any third party components or services? Third party stuff isn't an option in this case.

---

I have followed every tutorial I could find, and it just doesn't work. I cannot send an email to someone from a LightSwitch application, no matter how I do it. I can send email from WinForms, WPF, Websites - so I know it's not my code that's the problem.

I have followed this tutorial to a "T", and (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2011/01/27/how-to-send-html-email-from-a-lightswitch-application.aspx) it still won't work. First, here are my current issues:

1. In this tutorial, it tells you to add your Class.cs file to the UserCode folder in the Server folder - I did that.
2. It also tells you to Add a reference to System.Net.Mail (obviously) - I tried that. System.Net.Mail is not available to be added. I can't find it anywhere!
3. Every other tutorial is the same - so there's nothing else that I can try, that I know of.

As you can see below, I try adding System.Net.Mail as a reference, but it's not there in the list. I've also tried adding the `using System.Net.Mail` to the top of the files, but like I said; it's not available/does not exist/whatever.

[image]

Anyone know how to send email from a LightSwitch application?

Note, this is not a service, or website type project, just a simple Desktop Lightswitch app.

I have an invoice management app that I'm making, and the only part left is to auto-send a payment due reminder email if the payment is way overdue, based on the DateDue value in the table.

I've seen other comments on MSDN forums by people who said that System.Net.Mail is not available in Silverlight, and that's why it's not there in LightSwitch. I don't know if that's true or not, but it certainly is looking that way. Why couldn't they have just made System.Net.Mail available for LightSwitch apps without making us jump through hoops just to get it working?

Even though I said I know my code is fine, I'll post it anyway.

C#: (**Note that in my CLASS file System.Net.Mail IS available** HOWEVER, I am not able to access any part of this code in this file from anywhere else or any other file in my entire project!)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Web;

namespace LightSwitchApplication
{
    public class JTS
    {
        public class Mail
        {
            public string recipient { get; set; }
            public string subject { get; set; }
            public string message { get; set; }

            public void Send()
            {
                using (MailMessage mailmessage = new MailMessage())
                {
                    mailmessage.From = new MailAddress("@.com");
                    mailmessage.To.Add(recipient);
                    mailmessage.Subject = subject;
                    mailmessage.Body = message;
                    mailmessage.Priority = MailPriority.High;

                    using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient())
                    {
                        client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("@.com", "_SVN");
                        client.EnableSsl = false;
                        client.Host = "m..com";
                        client.Port = 25;
                        client.Send(mailmessage);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.Net.Mail` is a namespace, not an assembly. Try adding a reference to `System.Net` to see if that helps.

That tutorial you mentioned references
[this one](http://www.paulspatterson.com/technology/lightswitch/microsoft-lightswitch-send-an-email-from-lightswitch/), where it is `System.Net` they are adding the reference to.

Comment: I have added System.Net - but I still can't access this code in the JTS.cs class file.

Comment: By that do you mean that you are unable to create an instance of your `Mail` class? Maybe post some of the code you use when you try to send a message.

Comment: Yeah, you're spot on! I can't do `JTS jts = new JTS();` or `JTS.Mail mail = new JTS.Mail...` or anything like that - nothing shows in intellisense and it just gives me squiglies saying "JTS does not exist in the current context etc, but I can't `Resolve` it in context menu cause it "literally" does not exist for some reason

Comment: What if you access them as `LightSwitchApplication.JTS.Mail mail = LightSwitchApplication.JTS.Mail();` for example? You might also need to reference the project that `JTS` is in if your solution is split over multiple projects like the tutorials seem to be.

Comment: I tried that too (sorry I forgot to mention it) - `the type or namespace name 'JTS' does not exist in the namespace 'LightSwitchApplication'... are you missing an assembly ref?` - I can't add as using directive or assembly ref.

Comment: My project is just the single on, it's not split up :)

Comment: **I just noticed something important! **: My JTS.cs file is inside SERVER folder. But the CS file that VS generated for the Execute Command method is inside the CLIENT folder. I CAN ACCESS the JTS.cs file from within ANOTHER cs file IF both files are inside the SERVER folder. So I think this is the problem; code inside CLIENT directory cannot access code in server directory?

Comment: Can you find your objects in Object Browser (`Ctrl-W, J` in Visual Studio)? This might give you an idea of any namespace weirdness that might be going on.

Comment: Yeah! I can: `BAM\Server> LightSwitchApplication > JTS` (and also `JTS.Mail` - so I don't know why I can't access the code in server folder from within code in client folder

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19450/discussion-between-james-kent-and-nick-w)

Comment: but in Object Browser, it does not show my namespace for the CLIENT folder (which is where I need to access JTS from)

Comment: So the code in the Client directory, what namespace is that in?

Comment: Doing further reading in that link in posted in my answer, it would seem as though sending emails from the Client directory isn't allowed due to security - you will need to send the emails in the Server directory, probably in response to some event caused by an action by the client.

Comment: ok, but still, I would need to send something to the server code so that it can execute, but nothing in server code can be detected from client code :-/ RE your second-last comment, the code in my client directory is auto-generated code done by lightswitch which is inside these folders: Client > UserCode > CreateOrEditInvoice.cs. Client code is inside same namespace as my JTS.cs (server) code which is the LightSwitchApplication namespace

Comment: You don't need to access the server code from the client. What you need to do is place your emailing code in an event handler, just like in the tutorials. Lightswitch will take care of the wiring up. In many respects it seems a similar paradigm to the way we deal with events in ASP.NET.

Comment: Enjoy your 500 rep, I just realised I missed a part in that tutorial (several times) :-/ lol Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Will definitely enjoy the rep!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add a reference to *System.Net* to the **Server** project, as that project is a .NET project, that has no restrictions on what code you can use, unlike Silverlight projects. So, you would right-click the Server project, & select "Add Reference", then locate the System.Net assembly.

The methods in the articles DO work, but what may not be so apparent is that although you can work with .NET code in the *Server* project, you can't directly access that code (or your own code) from the *Client* project.

Have a look at this article about what we call the "[Command Table Pattern](http://blog.pragmaswitch.com/?p=332)" that's used to get around the fact that client project code can't directly call server project code.

Another alternative, is to use the [Office Integration Pack extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/35c4cf2a-5148-4716-afcf-0ccf8899cabf) that's available for free that "*makes it easy to manipulate the 2010 versions of Excel, Word and **Outlook** in a variety of ways common in desktop business applications. Create documents, PDFs, spreadsheets, **email** and appointments using data from your LightSwitch applications*".

And there's a [sample application](http://officeintegration.codeplex.com/downloads/get/420541) available for download as well.

I hope this helps.